# Find a compact set $S$ in topological semigroup $T$ with $SK\subseteq (T-K)$ for some compact set $K$

Tags: semigroups, topological-semigroups

Let $T$ be a topological semigroup and $K$ be a compact set in $T$. I know that if $T=(\mathbb{R}^n, +)$ or $T=(\mathbb{Z}^n, +)$, then for every compact set $K$ in $T$, there is compact set $S$ with $SK\subseteq (T-K)$. What can say about other topological semigroups?

Can we say that it does hold for any topological semigroup?
Please help me to know it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair,Thanks a lot. What the means of "distance from  $0$ is greater than twice the bound on $K$"? We know that $K$ is a compact set in topological semigroup $T$.

Comment: I was commenting on your two examples only. For some reason I thought you were asking first about them, then extending the question to more general semi-groups. I now see this was mistaken, and my reference to your examples was pointless. My apologies.

Comment: However, it seems likely that if $T$ has elements $v$ such that $nv \ne 0$ for all integers $n > 0$, then translation of $K$ by $w = nv$ for some sufficiently large $n$ would leave $wK \cap K = \emptyset$, allowing $S = \{w\}$ to work.